# Как можно сократить такой код?

Tags: java

Дело в том, что в каждой строке отличается уравнение. Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, но как такое можно сократить?

```
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMin - 0.5, zMin), new Location(getWorld(), xMax, yMin - 0.5, zMin)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMax + 0.5, zMin), new Location(getWorld(), xMax, yMax + 0.5, zMin)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMin - 0.5, zMax + 1), new Location(getWorld(), xMax, yMin - 0.5, zMax + 1)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMax + 0.5, zMax + 1), new Location(getWorld(), xMax, yMax + 0.5, zMax + 1)).build();

new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMin - 0.5, zMin), new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMax - 0.5, zMin)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMax + 1, yMin - 0.5, zMin), new Location(getWorld(), xMax + 1, yMax - 0.5, zMin)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMin - 0.5, zMax + 1), new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMax - 0.5, zMax + 1)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMax + 1, yMin - 0.5, zMax + 1), new Location(getWorld(), xMax + 1, yMax - 0.5, zMax + 1)).build();

new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMin - 0.5, zMin), new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMin - 0.5, zMax)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMax + 1, yMin - 0.5, zMin), new Location(getWorld(), xMax + 1, yMin - 0.5, zMax)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMax + 0.5, zMin), new Location(getWorld(), xMin, yMax + 0.5, zMax)).build();
new CrystalBeam(getPlugin(), player, new Location(getWorld(), xMax + 1, yMax + 0.5, zMin), new Location(getWorld(), xMax + 1, yMax + 0.5, zMax)).build();
```

Comment: Никак, мало масленое получается, при любой попытке как-то улучшить ты любо сделаешь код для чтения сложнее и для понимания тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете массив с параметрами для Location, идете по нему циклом, по этим параметрам создаете `Location` и `CrystalBeam`:

```
double[][] params = {
        {xMin, yMin - 0.5, zMin, xMax, yMin - 0.5, zMin},
        {xMin, yMax + 0.5, zMin, xMax, yMax + 0.5, zMin},
        {xMin, yMin - 0.5, zMax + 1, xMax, yMin - 0.5, zMax + 1},
        {xMin, yMax + 0.5, zMax + 1, xMax, yMax + 0.5, zMax + 1},
        // и т.д.
};

for (double[] row : params) {
    new CrystalBeam(
            getPlugin(), player,
            new Location(getWorld(), row[0], row[1], row[2]),
            new Location(getWorld(), row[3], row[4], row[5])
    ).build();
}
```

Comment: На мой взгляд этот вариант ничего не улучшает, если потребуется добавить в начало массива что-то ещё, то получается дальше в логике нужно менять индексы везде.

Но это не означает, что он не рабочий :)

Без обид, просто мнение :)

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко индексы только в строках массива используются для получения параметров объекта `Location`. Если нужно добавить CrystalBeam с другими параметрами, нужно просто добавить строку в массив, остальной код никак не изменится.

Comment: это если мы рассматриваем штатное использование и если мы добавляем в конец массива, но ведь может быть так, что нужно будет добавить в начало массива, что влечет за собой смещение индексов, по которым берутся значения ниже в коде.

Просто как по мне, то это масло масленое получается :)
А так че, такое решение имеет место быть :)

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко, еще раз, индексы используются только для "адресации" внутри строки. При добавлении строк в любое место массива индексы никак не меняются. Сами строки при этом должны быть фиксированной длины, естественно.

Comment: Грубо говоря, есть двумерная таблица с параметрами, колонок всегда 6 штук. Индексы используются именно для обращения к ячейкам внутри строк таблицы, ячеек в строках всегда 6. А строки - хоть обдобавляйся, хоть в начало, хоть в конец, хоть в середину - на количество колонок и на индексы ячеек внутри строк это никак не повлияет.

Comment: Блин, соррян, тупанул  :)

Answer (score 0):

Тут у Вас перебор вершин граней куба 1х1х1 по координатам вершин.

по оси у можно сделать замену переменной как

```
           yMin = yMin - 0.5, yMax = yMax - 0.5;
```

тогда у вас куб с вершинами

```
      (0,0,0), (0,0,1)
      (0,1,0), (0,1,1)
      (1,0,0), (1,0,1)
      (1,1,0), (1,1,1)
```

складывается с кубом
там где 0 - это минимум (xMin или yMin или zMin) a 1 - максимум соответственно
(xMax или yMax или zMax)

будет что-то по типу

```
(0 + xMin, 0 + yMin, 0+zMin), (0+xMin,0+yMin,1+zMax)
```

ну и заменой переменной можно вернуть назад.